# If $r$ is the inradius of $\triangle ABC$,then prove that $\frac{2}{r}=\frac{1}{r_a}+\frac{1}{r_b}+\frac{1}{r_c}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In acute angled triangle $ABC$,a semicircle with radius $r_a$ is constructed with its base on $BC$ and tangent to the other two sides.$r_b$ and $r_c$ are defined similarly.If $r$ is the inradius of $\triangle ABC$,then prove that $\frac{2}{r}=\frac{1}{r_a}+\frac{1}{r_b}+\frac{1}{r_c}$

---

I am stuck at this problem.I drew it but i could not fully understand the problem.No worth mentioning inputs from me.Please help.

Comment: What is the orgin of this problem? JEE?

Comment: *Trigonometry* by Hall and Knight ,Loney are good old references in India.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If a circle is tangent to $AB$ and $AC$, its centre lies on the bisector of $\widehat{BAC}$. If such a centre lies on $BC$, it is the feet $L_A$ of the angle bisector of $\widehat{BAC}$. By the bisector theorem:
$$ L_A B = \frac{ca}{b+c} $$
hence:
$$ r_A = L_A B \sin B = \frac{2\Delta}{b+c}. $$
On the other hand, it is trivial that $ r = \frac{2\Delta}{a+b+c}$, hence the claim is equivalent to:
$$ 2(a+b+c) = (a+b)+(a+c)+(b+c).$$

Comment: which editor or software you used to draw this picture, I am in the search of some user friendly tools through which I can draw complex geometrical shapes with ease.